# Notepad++ alternative with the ability to search in folder

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

I am looking for an alternative program on macOS, like Notepad++ with two abilities:

1. To write and edit program code,

and

2. Search specific string in a folder full of text files.

Comment: Emacs will do this - basically you are asking for the usual suspects Visual Code, Atom, Sublime Text and if you think notepad++ is OK then macVim - and there are lots of opinions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) is the editor you are looking for. It is available to download for free.

This text editor is pretty popular with software developers and users of macOS.

Sublime text includes powerful text editing features along with support for popular programming languages. It also lets you easily search within files in a folder.

---

**P.S.**: Sublime Text 3 may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use. Acquiring a license by paying one time fee removes the non-intrusive prompt to register the product and it is meant to support the developer behind the wonderful product.

[image]

A couple points of note from the [Sales FAQ](https://www.sublimetext.com/sales_faq) page:

> - A license is valid for Sublime Text 3, and includes all point updates, as well as access to prior versions (e.g., Sublime Text 2). Future major versions, such as Sublime Text 4, will be a paid upgrade.
> - Licenses purchased for Sublime Text 3 do not expire, however an upgrade fee will be required for Sublime Text 4.

**P.P.S.**: I have no-affiliation whatsoever with the developer. This is a wonderful app which is widely popular among both casual users and software developers.

Comment: it is what I want. but it should be better free.

Comment: @D.JCode It indeed is free. The unregistered version is free to use, forever, with all the features available. Registering the product simply removes the unregistered title from the title bar and the prompt requesting to register (which is shown once in a while). It is encouraged to register to support the programmer behind the app.

Comment: I don't know it. thank you so much.

Comment: When did Sublime Text become a free app?  Someone needs to let the developer know, they don't seem to agree with you.

Comment: @MarcWilson Thanks for mentioning. I have updated the answer. However, the requirement of procuring a license is not enforced, and technically, the product can be evaluated forever. For the same reason, I have mentioned that purchasing license is meant to support the developer.

Comment: @MarcWilson I have edited the answer to add further clarification. I never mentioned in the answer that the editor is free to use, rather free to download and evaluate. Let me know if the edit is helpful and makes the point clear.

Answer (score 1):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) is another great editor that has the features you are looking for, with the added benefit of being free and open source.

A good comparison of Atom and Sublime Text 3 can be found [here](https://www.codementor.io/mattgoldspink/best-text-editor-atom-sublime-vim-visual-studio-code-du10872i7)

Comment: in Atom I can not find a tool to search a word in text files.